# DateTime createFromFormat Issue

Tags: php, datetime

I'm trying to get a datetime format conversion to work and am having trouble. The format I've specified doesn't seem to work with the input I've given. I've never used this function before so any tips would be appreciated.

I'm trying to do the following conversions:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('l, F j Y g.ia','Thursday, April 2 2014 7.20pm');
$date = $date->format('d/m/Y');
```

I get a "Fatal error:  Call to a member function format() on a non-object in  on line 76" which I'm guessing means the createFromFormat function is failing.

Any ideas?

Comment: what PHP version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the late response.

Rakesh was right. The date I was putting in was invalid, so the more recent version of PHP was less-forgiving than older versions.

I did a side by side comparison with versions of PHP. Current PHP version seems to throw an error. Older versions seem to correct the date on a best effort basis.

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime::createFromFormat` or `date_create_from_format` function are supported only in PHP 5 >= 5.3.0.

Hence, to make it work you will need to either :

- Upgrade your PHP version to 5.3.0 or more

OR

- Try using the

  ```
  $date = date('d/m/Y',strtotime('Thursday, April 2 2014 7.20pm'));
  echo $date;
  ```

NOTE: php version 5.3.0 - 5.3.8 shows the date formatted to 02/04/2014 while php version 5.3.9 - 5.6.3 shows the formatted date as 03/04/2014. It is because DateTime seems to be more strict in php version 5.3.9 - 5.6.3 than php version 5.3.0 - 5.3.8. As what i could notice is the day we try to convert if does not sync with its weekday. Means, April 2 is not the Thursday and its is actually the Wednesday, Hence it forces the date which falls on the Thursday near to the day you specified in your date. Like if we will try to convert the date 'Thursday, April 4 2014 7.20pm', we will end up showing the 10th april because Thursday falls on this date.

Comment: I'm using PHP v5.4.4. The function is running but it doesn't seem to like my expression for the date format I gave.

Comment: It does work at my end like you can also check here : http://3v4l.org/g4St1 . You can do one thing, if you can get to know and share the last error using DateTime::getLastErrors() putting it above your format() function, we can have some more idea. Moreover, i could , while checking this, see one strange results where for php version 5.3.0 - 5.3.8 it shows the date formatted to me as 02/04/2014 while for php version 5.3.9 - 5.6.3 it shows the formatted date as 03/04/2014.

Comment: Cheers Rakesh. It appears to be working now. All I changed was the timezone in php.ini? Anyway - the resulting date appears to be incorrect by one day. Is this a timezone issue? I've set the default in php.ini. Any suggestions?

Comment: i could see the same as i told you in my prev comments - "Moreover, i could , while checking this, see one strange results where for php version 5.3.0 - 5.3.8 it shows the date formatted to me as 02/04/2014 while for php version 5.3.9 - 5.6.3 it shows the formatted date as 03/04/2014"

Comment: i am digging on it and will share the findings here

Comment: Yeah sorry I only saw the second part of your comment after I'd posted. Let me know if you find anything. Thanks.

Comment: Seonix, i think DateTime seems to be more strict in php version 5.3.9 - 5.6.3 than php version 5.3.0 - 5.3.8. As what i could dig is the day you are trying to convert does not sync with its weekday. Means, April 2 is not the Thursday, Hence it forces the date which falls on the Thursday near to the day you specified in your date. Like if you will try to convert the date  'Thursday, April 4 2014 7.20pm', you will end up showing the 10th april because Thursday falls on this date.